# Rails: Retrieve the latest record from multiple associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm looking for an optimal and better performing solution to fetch the latest record among multiple has-many associations,

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base`
  has_many books
  has_many tables
  has_many chairs
end
```

I have the following so far, to achieve retrieval of the last among these associations.

```
[books.last, tables.last, chairs.last]
  .compact
  .sort_by(&:created_at)
  .last
```

This produces several queries which in turn slows down the response through the controller. Is there a better solution to achieve the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could create a SQL View, selecting the latest entity from several tables, and then link that table to a Rails read-only model.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have:

```
class Publisher
  has_many :books
end

class Book
  belongs_to :publisher
end
```

You can use `DISTINCT ON` to fetch the latest rows:

```
Book.distinct('ON(books.publisher_id)').order(created_at: :desc)
```

You can use this limit the number of associated rows loaded:

```
Publisher.includes(:books)
   .where(books: Book.distinct('ON(books.publisher_id').order(created_at: :desc))
```

Rails is smart enough to bake it into a single query.

Doing this for multiple assocations is exactly the same:

```
Publisher.includes(:books, :records)
   .where(
     books: Book.distinct('ON(books.publisher_id').order(created_at: :desc),
     records:  Record.distinct('ON(record.publisher_id').order(created_at: :desc)
   )
```

And this will only load one book. There are several more performant options such as lateral joins but they are messier to integrate. But if you are often reading from the table it may make sense to store the latest associated record on the parent table:

```
class Publisher
  has_many :books, after_add: :set_latest_book!
  belongs_to :latest_book

  def set_latest_book!(book)
    self.update_attribute!(:latest_book_id, book.id)
  end
end

class Book
  belongs_to :publisher
end
```

This lets you eager load / include with a simple query and performant query:

```
Publisher.eager_load(:latest_book)
```

Comment: You can also use a trigger to update when rows are inserted into the associated table. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is Postgres specific and won't work if you are using SQLite for dev/test.

Answer (score 0):

UNION in SQL can help you. Union will include all your queries and you will be able to sort it easily.

```
SELECT id, 'Book' AS type, created_at, other_fields FROM books
UNION
SELECT id, 'Table' AS type, created_at, other_fields FROM tables
UNION
SELECT id, 'Chair' AS type, created_at, other_fields FROM chairs
ORDER BY created_at;
```

Note that you can union by common fields across different tables. So you can't select some field, that does not exist in other fields. Field `type` is necessary to differ entities.